# Keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to change a shortcut in Eclipse that when I press that shortcut Eclipse will write some line of code? Let's say I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> would it be possible that Eclipse will write `<p></p>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the templates support.

*Window* → *Preferences* → *Java* → *Editor* → *Templates*

Here is an article describing [custom eclipse templates](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no, but as aioobe answered, you can use templates for it. Instead of that keyboard combo, you'd instead type something like `par` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get Eclipse's autosuggest for creating an paragraph open / close tag (with the cursor in the middle). This'll either display a dropdown if Eclipse is unsure, or just chuck your template down if it has no doubts.

Note also that, when editing HTML files (or anything XML~like), you can get Eclipse to auto-close tags, so typing `<p>` will automatically add a closing tag too. This might of course be a bit trickier due to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> keyboard combo's (depending on your finger's agility and, possibly, keyboard configuration). I have no trouble with it though.